# Radius of Convergence and Interval of Convergence: Am I doing it right?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I must find ROC and IOC in
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{{(-1)}^n(x^{2n})}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+4n}}
$$

I get
$$
R= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left| \frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} \right| = \cdots = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\sqrt[3]{\frac{n^2+6n+5}{n^2+4n}} = 1
$$
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+4n}}=0
$$
$$
\left|x^2\right|<1
$$
$$
-1<x<1
$$
Is that right?

Comment: You may need to determine convergence or divergence in the end points of the interval. Not if the interval of convergence is by definition always open, but otherwise you need to.

Comment: I guees this $2k$ over $x$ should be a $2n$. Yes, the ROC is correct. Convergence for $x=\pm 1$ amounts to the convergence of $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt[3]{n^2+4n}}$, so you'll need to address that.